# Call object method from child object(PHP)

Tags: php, oop

Say object of class B is attribute of class A. How can I call method of object of class A from method of object of class B? What would be nice solution without passing object link?

Thanks!

Here goes code sample:

```
class A{
    var $b;

    function __construct(){
        $this->b = new B();
    }

    function f1(){
        $this->b->f3();
    }        

    function f2(){
        echo 'hello!';
    }
}

class B{
    function f3(){
         // call f2() method in object $obj(not new A())
    }
}

$obj = new A();
$obj->f1();
```

Comment: I think your only way is to pass `$this` to `f3()`.

Comment: Read about `dependency injection`. Your use of `var b;` tells me that you are used to veryyyyy old PHP4 code. PHP5 offers great new possibilities and easy design pattern integration!

Comment: Anyone else unable to post an answer to this question for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static function

```
public static function f2{
    echo 'hello!';
}
```

with f3 defined as

```
function f3(){
    A::f2();
}
```

This may not ultimately be the solution you want, however. See more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Static_methods).

Comment: Unless the function has references to the current instance.

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer with a link to make that more clear.

Comment: Depending on what `f2()` does then this could work :-)

Comment: Thanks!
Another similar question(separated from example above):

For example function f() is being called from functions f1() and f2(). How to find out which function called f()?

Like
    function f(){ /* echo callerFunctionName();*/}

Comment: And you don't want to pass anything to f()? The easiest solution would be to pass a string to `f(var name) { echo name; }` and then call f like `f1() { f("echo this"); }`

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can access that instance's function is if you inject it on the `B` object as a dependency. You can inject it within the constructor, like this:

```
<?php

class A {
    protected $b;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->b = new B($this);
    }

    public function f1() {
        $this->b->f3();
    }        

    public function f2() {
        echo 'hello!';
    }
}

class B {
    protected $a;

    public function __construct($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function f3() {
        $this->a->f2();
    }
}

$obj = new A();
$obj->f1();
```